# Qt Creator QPixmap doesn't upload an image

Tags: c++, qt

I've been struggling in uploading an image to a button using a setIcon() function in my Qt project.
So, what I did was, copying the image in the same folder of the .pro file, create a resource file, create a prefix in the resource file and in the end, I added the image to the resource.

Then, I tried to apply it to a QPixmap in order to use it with an Icon and then use this image inside a button. That's how I did it:

```
QPixmap pix(":/images/roadplus.JPG");

QIcon icon(pix);

if(icon.isNull()) error_message("no image");

ui->button_add->setIcon(icon);
ui->button_add->setIconSize(pix.size());
```

Now, the error_message function is just a function that I use to show errors, I'm using it in order to debug my program and it shows the error message in that point, meaning that icon is actually null...
The path of the image should be correct, what I did was "right click -> copy path" from the left file explorer in Qt Creator and then just pasted it in the function.

I tried to find a solution on the web, but I didn't find something that could fix it, the only way would be using this line:

```
QPixmap pix("C:\\Users\\dopeo\\Desktop\\TrafficLightSimulator_QT\\roadplus.JPG");
```

But I would prefer path of the image that I added in the the resource, instead of the full path, any way to do it?

My resources appear like this:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/images">
    <file>roadplus.JPG</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your resources file?

Comment: @RomhaKorev Sorry about that, I just did